# Android checkbox tappable area not increasing

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have a checkbox in a listview.  It is very difficult to tap on the checkbox. 
 The tappable area is very small, I have checked few answers for this in stackoverflow, but none worked.  Please can anyone help how to increase the tappable area of a checkbox in android.

the code of my checkbox-

```
 <CheckBox android:id="@+id/CheckBox"
 android:layout_width="0dip"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
 android:layout_weight="0.05"
 android:button="@drawable/white_checkbox"
 android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: the code of my checkbox-
<CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/CheckBox"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:button="@drawable/white_checkbox"
        android:visibility="visible" />

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide additional code or XML. Please don't post it in comments.

Comment: sorry for it, actually i was not able to add it in the question, it was giving errors

Comment: Use setOnClickListener instead and check if checkbox.isChecked() equals true or false. If you do not have enough with that add more padding to the checkbox like padding="5dp".

Answer (score 1):

you can increas checkbox size like this one is work for me.

```
<CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleX="1.80"
        android:scaleY="1.80" />
```

As you required change scaleX and scaleY.

Comment: I tried this, but the size of the checkbox increased. and also I m not able to  select the checkbox. I want the size of the checkbox should be same.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comment add padding to increase the touch area

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.05"
    android:button="@drawable/white_checkbox"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Checkbox drawable will be decentered as it has a text field on the right. To have a centered drawable you can do the following modifications

```
android:button="@null"
android:drawableStart="@drawable/white_checkbox"
```

According to [Material Design - Layout metrics and keylines](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-touch-target-size)

touch targets should be at least 48 x 48 dp. So modify the padding accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution simple.
In checbox image is drawable left, by changing it to drawableRight padding work ad image is centered:
Drawalbe of selector is from default on left, change it on right solve issue:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox       
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:button="@null"
     android:drawableEnd="@drawable/custom_checkbox_selector"
     android:paddingStart="15dp"
     android:paddingTop="15dp"
     android:paddingEnd="15dp"
     android:paddingBottom="15dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding padding was causing my checkbox to not be centered. The following worked for me, however I specified a fixed size for the checkbox (as per my UI spec). The idea was to add padding to the left and not to the right (I had another label to the right). I added padding to the top and bottom too making the touch target larger and still keeping the checkbox centered.

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox"
        android:checked="false"
        android:gravity="center"
       />
```